# virutal-box not installing or deleting

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualbox

how to delete and re-install virtualbox so it works

```
master@666:~$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox 
[sudo] password for master: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kbuild libfprint-2-tod1 libgsoap-2.8.91 libllvm10 libllvm10:i386
  libqt5opengl5 libsdl1.2debian libvncserver1 linux-headers-5.4.0-42
  linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic
  module-assistant virtualbox-source
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 112 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 211357 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpk
```

Comment: `[Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'` Often `/var/crash/` contains old crash reports that are good to be cleaned out. I don't know whether in this case this is the cause of the error, but it would be worth trying to remove, or keep but move elsewhere (if you want to study them) virtualbox-related files from `/var/crash/`.

Comment: Your output: `Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.`

Comment: virtualbox can not build against kernel 5.8. I had the same problem. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo dkms remove -m virtualbox -v 6.1.10  k --all
```

This is an attempt to remove virtualbox from all kernel versions.

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox
```

If apt ist not working

```
sudo dpkg -P virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
```

I hope I remember my solution right.

Comment: I tried this `sudo dkms remove -m virtualbox -v 6.1.10 -k --all` but I get `Error! There is no instance of virtualbox 6.1.10` ... eventhouhg `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox` shows `6.1.10` ... any ideas?

Comment: `dkms status`  please.

Comment: `dkms status
virtualbox, 6.1.10: added`

Comment: `sudo dkms remove virtualbox/6.1.10 --all`

Comment: Done, but virtualbox 6.1.10 is still there ... `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox | grep 6.1.10
ic  virtualbox                                 6.1.10-....`

Comment: `sudo dpkg -P virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt`

Comment: that did it ... thanks!

Comment: This worked thank you all for those the contributed.